# Multiple matrix outputs from a for loop

Tags: r

As usual, I feel I'm missing something horribly simple, but I'm trying to get a for loop to output me a number of versions of the results of another for loop.

The code:

```
#Create Species Vector
  species.v <- letters[1:5]

  #Matrix creation (Random)
  start.matrix <- matrix(sample(species.v,25,replace=TRUE),
                      nrow=5,
                      ncol=5)

  result.matrix <- vector("list",25)

  for (i in 1:10) {
    for (i in 1:50) {
      in.dex <- sample(length(start.matrix),1)
      start.matrix[in.dex] <- as.character(sample(start.matrix,1))
    }

    result.matrix[[i]] <- start.matrix
  }
```

While the loop for index/sample/replacement is an extremely simplified version of what I'm doing, it has the same result. I'd then need to repeat this loop a number of times (in this example 10) and keep each output for later analysis/comparison.

I'd rather not do it through writing a new file (e.g. CSV) as I'll be doing my analysis in R anyway, but I can't seem to get the actual output to multiple files to work.

In the above example I tried to create a "result.matrix" vector as a list, though if the output is easier as a matrix that's fine - I just kept getting

> Error in result.matrix[[i]] <- start.matrix :    more elements
>   supplied than there are to replace

returned when I had result.matrix set up as a 5x5 matrix (either empty or with stuff in).

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why are both your loops indexed by `i`?

Comment: The second loop should have a different index, such as j.

Comment: And the length of your list does not correspond to either of your indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer to your question, based on the description of your problem, is to fix your code in two places:

```
#Create Species Vector
species.v <- letters[1:5]

#Matrix creation (Random)
start.matrix <- matrix(sample(species.v,25,replace=TRUE),
                       nrow=5,
                       ncol=5)

result.matrix <- vector("list",10)  # Changed here

for (i in 1:10) {
  for (j in 1:50) {                 # Changed here
      in.dex <- sample(length(start.matrix),1)
      start.matrix[in.dex] <- as.character(sample(start.matrix,1))
  }    
  result.matrix[[i]] <- start.matrix
}
```